# Redrawing background using ResizeObserver causes flashing in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm using [Trianglify](https://trianglify.io/) to create backgrounds for a div element. I wanted to write the function to regenerate the background anytime the window is resized.

Here is the function that adds the generated png to the div.

```
const header = document.querySelector('#header');

const addBackground = target =>{
    const dimensions = target.getClientRects()[0];
  const pattern = Trianglify({
    width: dimensions.width,
    height: dimensions.height,
    cell_size: Math.random()*200 + 40
  });

  target.style['background-image'] = 'url(' + pattern.png() + ')';
}

addBackground(header);
```

And here is the ResizeObserver

```
const ro = new ResizeObserver( () => {
  addBackground(header);
});

ro.observe(header);
```

This works fine in chrome and edge but it creates an effect in FireFox where the background image isn't generated until the user is done resizing. This would be fine if it didn't clear the background during the resizing.

I've created a fiddle that recreates the issue.

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahdz8k9/)